# Connect Power BI to Greenplum error "unrecognized configuration parameter ssl_renegotiation_limit"

Tags: powerbi, greenplum

I've encountered "*unrecognized configuration parameter ssl_renegotiation_limit*" when im trying to connect Power BI to Greenplum DB (PostgreSQL 8.2.15 and this GP DB using SSL) and I've already add my GP DB SSL certificate to my machine.

in the online documentation suggest to set **ssl_renegotiation_limit** parameter in *postgresql.conf* to '0' to avoid this kind of error, but the problem is I can't find any **ssl_renegotiation_limit** parameter in my *postgresql.conf* file.

is there any other way to setup the ssl_renegotiation_limit parameter in GP DB or there's another way to avoid the error above?

Answer (score 0):

This Power BI thing seems to be vintage software. `ssl_renegotiation_limit` has been *removed* from PostgreSQL years ago. Greenplum, on the other hand, maybe never had the parameter at all, because it is such an old fork.

You should use a version of Power BI that has got hip to the fact that there is no such parameter in PostgreSQL. If there is no such version, report it as a bug.